# my mvc controller for create operation is not uploading data to sql server

Tags: c#, html, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have to upload simple data to my server but in create page after I enter data and submit it, it doesn't no upload the data to database but it works fine as it returns to index menu and shows all other entries in database just it won't upload any new data

[Create page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoZFQ.png)

[No Changes occur to database but data s fetched properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2HSc.png)

following are the codes

Html for 'create page'

```
 @model SnackoEntities.DealMasterInfo


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>DealMasterInfo</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DealAutoID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DealAutoID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DealAutoID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FK_RestoID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FK_RestoID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FK_RestoID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FK_SnFoodID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FK_SnFoodID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FK_SnFoodID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FK_RoFoodID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FK_RoFoodID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FK_RoFoodID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DealDisPerc, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DealDisPerc, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DealDisPerc, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FK_RewaID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FK_RewaID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FK_RewaID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.startDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.startDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.startDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.endDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.endDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.endDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ValidOn, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ValidOn, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ValidOn, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserTypes, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserTypes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserTypes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DealCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DealCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DealCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DealPic, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DealPic, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DealPic, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DealStatus, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DealStatus, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DealStatus, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreatedOn, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreatedOn, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreatedOn, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>q

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ModifiedOn, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ModifiedOn, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ModifiedOn, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreatedBy, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreatedBy, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreatedBy, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

My controller

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("Create")]
public ActionResult Create_get()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Create")]
public ActionResult Create_post(DealMasterInfo dealMasterInfo)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //DealMasterInfo dealMasterInfo = new DealMasterInfo();
        UpdateModel(dealMasterInfo);
        DealMasterBLL dealMasterBLL = new DealMasterBLL();
        dealMasterBLL.AddDealMaster(dealMasterInfo);
        if (dealMasterInfo != null)
        {

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

Bll code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using SnackoEntities;

namespace BusinesssLayer
{
   public class DealMasterBLL
    {
        public IEnumerable<DealMasterInfo> DealMasterInfo
        {
            get
            {
                string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DealMaster"].ConnectionString;

                List<DealMasterInfo> dealMasterInfos = new List<DealMasterInfo>();

                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetDealMasterInfo", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        DealMasterInfo dealMasterInfo = new DealMasterInfo();
                        dealMasterInfo.DealAutoID = rdr["DealAutoID"].ToString();
                        dealMasterInfo.FK_RestoID = rdr["FK_RestoID"].ToString();
                        dealMasterInfo.FK_SnFoodID = rdr["FK_SnFoodID"].ToString();
                        dealMasterInfo.DealDisPerc = rdr["DealDisPerc"].ToString();
                        dealMasterInfo.FK_RewaID = rdr["FK_RewaID"].ToString();
                        dealMasterInfo.startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["startDate"]);
                        dealMasterInfo.endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["endDate"]);
                        dealMasterInfo.ValidOn = rdr["ValidOn"].ToString();
                        dealMasterInfo.UserTypes = rdr["UserTypes"].ToString();
                        dealMasterInfo.DealCode = rdr["DealCode"].ToString();
                        dealMasterInfo.DealPic = rdr["DealPic"].ToString();
                        dealMasterInfo.DealStatus = rdr["DealStatus"].ToString();
                        dealMasterInfo.CreatedOn = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["CreatedOn"]);
                        dealMasterInfo.ModifiedOn = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["ModifiedOn"]);
                        dealMasterInfo.CreatedBy = rdr["CreatedBy"].ToString();

                        dealMasterInfos.Add(dealMasterInfo);
                    }
                }

                return dealMasterInfos;
            }
        }

        public void AddDealMaster(DealMasterInfo dealMasterInfo)
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DealMaster"].ConnectionString;

            try
            {
                using(SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spAddDealMaster", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    SqlParameter paramDealAutoID = new SqlParameter();
                    paramDealAutoID.ParameterName = "@DealAuto";
                    paramDealAutoID.Value = dealMasterInfo.DealAutoID;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramDealAutoID);

                    SqlParameter paramFK_RestoID = new SqlParameter();
                    paramFK_RestoID.ParameterName = "@FK_RestoID";
                    paramFK_RestoID.Value = dealMasterInfo.FK_RestoID;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramFK_RestoID);

                    SqlParameter paramFK_SnFoodID = new SqlParameter();
                    paramFK_SnFoodID.ParameterName = "@FK_SnFoodID";
                    paramFK_SnFoodID.Value = dealMasterInfo.FK_SnFoodID;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramFK_SnFoodID);

                    SqlParameter paramFK_RoFoodID = new SqlParameter();
                    paramFK_RoFoodID.ParameterName = "@FK_RoFoodID";
                    paramFK_RoFoodID.Value = dealMasterInfo.FK_RoFoodID;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramFK_RoFoodID);

                    SqlParameter paramDealDisPerc = new SqlParameter();
                    paramDealDisPerc.ParameterName = "@DealDisPerc";
                    paramDealDisPerc.Value = dealMasterInfo.DealDisPerc;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramDealDisPerc);

                    SqlParameter paramFK_RewaID = new SqlParameter();
                    paramFK_RewaID.ParameterName = "@FK_RewaID";
                    paramFK_RewaID.Value = dealMasterInfo.FK_RewaID;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramFK_RewaID);

                    SqlParameter paramstartDate = new SqlParameter();
                    paramstartDate.ParameterName = "@startDate";
                    paramstartDate.Value = dealMasterInfo.startDate;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramstartDate);

                    SqlParameter paramendDate = new SqlParameter();
                    paramendDate.ParameterName = "@endDate";
                    paramendDate.Value = dealMasterInfo.endDate;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramendDate);

                    SqlParameter paramValidOn = new SqlParameter();
                    paramValidOn.ParameterName = "@ValidOn";
                    paramValidOn.Value = dealMasterInfo.ValidOn;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramValidOn);

                    SqlParameter paramUserTypes = new SqlParameter();
                    paramUserTypes.ParameterName = "@UserTypes";
                    paramUserTypes.Value = dealMasterInfo.UserTypes;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramUserTypes);

                    SqlParameter paramDealCode = new SqlParameter();
                    paramDealCode.ParameterName = "@DealCode";
                    paramDealCode.Value = dealMasterInfo.DealCode;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramDealCode);

                    SqlParameter paramDealPic = new SqlParameter();
                    paramDealPic.ParameterName = "@DealPic";
                    paramDealPic.Value = dealMasterInfo.DealPic;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramDealPic);

                    SqlParameter paramDealStatus = new SqlParameter();
                    paramDealStatus.ParameterName = "@DealStatus";
                    paramDealStatus.Value = dealMasterInfo.DealStatus;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramDealStatus);

                    SqlParameter paramCreatedOn = new SqlParameter();
                    paramCreatedOn.ParameterName = "@CreatedOn";
                    paramCreatedOn.Value = dealMasterInfo.CreatedOn;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramCreatedOn);

                    SqlParameter paramModifiedOn = new SqlParameter();
                    paramModifiedOn.ParameterName = "@ModifiedOn";
                    paramModifiedOn.Value = dealMasterInfo.ModifiedOn;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramModifiedOn);

                    SqlParameter paramCreatedBy = new SqlParameter();
                    paramCreatedBy.ParameterName = "@CreatedBy";
                    paramCreatedBy.Value = dealMasterInfo.CreatedBy;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramCreatedBy);

                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                Console.WriteLine("SQL Error" + ex.Message.ToString());
            }

        }

    }
}
```

entity class

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SnackoEntities
{
    public class DealMasterInfo
    {
        public string DealAutoID { get; set; }
        public string FK_RestoID { get; set; }
        public string FK_SnFoodID { get; set; }
        public string FK_RoFoodID { get; set; }
        public string DealDisPerc { get; set; }
        public string FK_RewaID { get; set; }
        public DateTime startDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime endDate { get; set; }
        public string ValidOn { get; set; }
        public string UserTypes { get; set; }
        public string DealCode { get; set; } 
        public string DealPic { get; set; }
        public string DealStatus { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am learning MVC and this is my first project, so please with the solution give an explanation in easy language so that I can understand the problem in future

Comment: your problem is most likely in the bll code, which you did not provide (you pasted your controller again by mistake)

Comment: How are we supposed to guess what your `AddDealMaster()` method does

Comment: Disclose your UpdateModel() method

Comment: I have added the bll I had by mistake added create twice and updatemodel is the mvc function(from updatemodel() and tryupdatemodel() functions of mvc) to update the data to model

Comment: Please help stuck on this for few days now

Comment: As a side note, your `if (ModelState.IsValid)` is pointless since your using `FormCollection`. But you should never use `FormCollection` - your method should be `public ActionResult Create_post(DealMasterInfo model)`

Comment: Debug and see what actually going wrong @Goku

Comment: @ZiaulKabirFahad i did debug the code runs properly and goes through each path but thereis no Change to database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a spelling mistake in the code due to which it wasn't working
the

```
SqlParameter paramDealDisPerc = new SqlParameter();
                paramDealDisPerc.ParameterName = "@DealDisPerc";
                paramDealDisPerc.Value = dealMasterInfo.DealDisPerc;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramDealDisPerc);
```

here the DealDiscPerc Should have been DealDiscPerc

```
SqlParameter paramDealDisPerc = new SqlParameter();
                paramDealDisPerc.ParameterName = "@DealDiscPerc";
                paramDealDisPerc.Value = dealMasterInfo.DealDisPerc;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramDealDisPerc);
```

did this mistake because my table had same variable without "C" whereas while writing SP i added a "C" and this caused the confusion 
this solved the issue